# Como ler um json usando Gson quando a classe contém ArrayList's em JAVA

Tags: java

Olá, estou fazendo um trabalho de faculdade e estou tendo problemas para simular uma persistência. A idéia é o seguinte, eu tenho uma classe Observable/Singleton que faz tanto o controle de atualização de dados de algumas listas quanto faz a armazenagem e a importação desses dados de um json. Abaixo segue meu código:

```
/**
 * Singleton class. Representa uma estrutura simples de base de dados mantendo as
 * informações em um arquivo JSON no root da aplicação.
 */
public class Db extends Observable {

    // construtores
    private Db() {
        fileName = "db.json";
        assinantes = new ArrayList<>();
        mensagens = new ArrayList<>();
        regras = new ArrayList<>();
        conquistas = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private Db(int i) throws IOException {
        fileName = "db.json";
        try {
            get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            assinantes = new ArrayList<>();
            mensagens = new ArrayList<>();
            regras = new ArrayList<>();
            conquistas = new ArrayList<>();
            set();
        }
    }

    // implementação singleton
    private static Db instance;

    public static Db getInstance() throws IOException {
        if (instance == null) instance = new Db(0);
        return instance;
    }

    // implementação persistence
    protected String fileName;

    // getters & setters
    private ArrayList<AssinanteFree> assinantes;

    public ArrayList<AssinanteFree> getAssinantes() {
        return instance.assinantes;
    }

    public void setAssinantes(ArrayList<AssinanteFree> v) {
        assinantes = v;
        emit();
    }

    private ArrayList<Mensagem> mensagens;

    public ArrayList<Mensagem> getMensagens() {
        return instance.mensagens;
    }

    public void setMensagens(ArrayList<Mensagem> v) {
        mensagens = v;
        emit();
    }

    private ArrayList<Regra> regras;

    public ArrayList<Regra> getRegras() {
        return instance.regras;
    }

    private ArrayList<Conquista> conquistas;

    public ArrayList<Conquista> getConquistas() {
        return instance.conquistas;
    }

    // methods
    private void emit() {
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }

    private void get() throws IOException {
        try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(fileName)) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            instance = gson.fromJson(reader, Db.class);
        }
    }

    private void set() throws IOException {
        try (Writer writer = new FileWriter(fileName)) {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            gson.toJson(this, writer);
        }
    }

}
```

Meu problema é o seguinte. Eu consigo puxar um arquivo json para essa classe, tanto que ele até popula os outros campos que não são do tipo `ArrayList<T>` mas nestes (que são os que mais importam) eu não consigo puxar... Abaixo está o arquivo json que estou usando:

```
{
    "fileName": "db.json",
    "assinantes": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "nome": "Leandro",
            "tipo": "Vip",
            "pontuacao": 0,
            "dataCriado": "2018-06-27 05:00:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "nome": "André",
            "tipo": "Premium",
            "pontuacao": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "nome": "Maria",
            "tipo": "Free"
        }
    ],
    "mensagens": [],
    "regras": [
        { "tipo": "Free", "limiteMsg": 50, "addPontos": 0 },
        { "tipo": "Premium", "limiteMsg": 75, "addPontos": 1 }, 
        { "tipo": "Vip", "limiteMsg": 100, "addPontos": 1.4 }

    ],
    "conquistas": [
        { "descricao": "Novato", "minimo": 0 },
        { "descricao": "Iniciante", "minimo": 1 },
        { "descricao": "Experiente", "minimo": 4 },
        { "descricao": "Sênior", "minimo": 10 },
        { "descricao": "Legendario", "minimo": 100 }
    ],
    "changed": false,
    "obs": []
}
```

Como faço para importar os ArrayList's ?

Comment: Esse Json é assim mesmo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisa ser criado a classe que vai carregar essas informações, mas, o que eu pude perceber que o `array` de assinantes não possui um padrão e isso faz com que os dados não sejam carregados ocasionando uma exceção se o campo `dataCriado` estiver configurado como `Date` (que seria o correto) mas, para contornar isso fiz o exemplo com o tipo `String` ai é carregado normalmente:

**Classes:**

*Assinantes:*

```
package Classes;
public class Assinantes {
    private int id;
    private String nome;
    private int pontuacao;
    private String dataCriado;    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public int getPontuacao() {
        return pontuacao;
    }
    public String getDataCriado() {
        return dataCriado;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public void setPontuacao(int pontuacao) {
        this.pontuacao = pontuacao;
    }
    public void setDataCriado(String dataCriado) {
        this.dataCriado = dataCriado;
    }    
}
```

*Conquistas:*

```
package Classes;
public class Conquistas {
    private String descricao;
    private int minimo;    
    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }
    public int getMinimo() {
        return minimo;
    }
    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }
    public void setMinimo(int minimo) {
        this.minimo = minimo;
    }    
}
```

*Mensagens:*

```
package Classes;
public class Mensagens {

}
```

*Obs:*

```
package Classes;
public class Obs {

}
```

*Regras:*

```
package Classes;
public class Regras {
    private String tipo;
    private String limiteMsg;
    private Double addPontos;    
    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }
    public String getLimiteMsg() {
        return limiteMsg;
    }
    public Double getAddPontos() {
        return addPontos;
    }
    public void setTipo(String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }
    public void setLimiteMsg(String limiteMsg) {
        this.limiteMsg = limiteMsg;
    }
    public void setAddPontos(Double addPontos) {
        this.addPontos = addPontos;
    }    
}
```

*Root:*

```
package Classes;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Root {
    private String fileName;
    private ArrayList<Regras> regras;
    private ArrayList<Assinantes> assinantes;
    private ArrayList<Conquistas> conquistas;
    private boolean changed;
    private ArrayList<Mensagens> mensagens;
    private ArrayList<Obs> obs; 
    public ArrayList<Regras> getRegras() {
        return regras;
    }
    public void setRegras(ArrayList<Regras> regras) {
        this.regras = regras;
    }
    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }
    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }
    public ArrayList<Assinantes> getAssinantes() {
        return assinantes;
    }
    public void setAssinantes(ArrayList<Assinantes> assinantes) {
        this.assinantes = assinantes;
    }
    public ArrayList<Conquistas> getConquistas() {
        return conquistas;
    }
    public void setConquistas(ArrayList<Conquistas> conquistas) {
        this.conquistas = conquistas;
    }
    public boolean isChanged() {
        return changed;
    }
    public void setChanged(boolean changed) {
        this.changed = changed;
    }
    public ArrayList<Mensagens> getMensagens() {
        return mensagens;
    }
    public ArrayList<Obs> getObs() {
        return obs;
    }
    public void setMensagens(ArrayList<Mensagens> mensagens) {
        this.mensagens = mensagens;
    }
    public void setObs(ArrayList<Obs> obs) {
        this.obs = obs;
    }
}
```

Basicamente essas classes carregam o `json` da pergunta utilizando a biblioteca [com.google.code.gson](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.6.2/) da seguinte forma:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\db.json"));
Root obj = gson.fromJson(br, Root.class);
```

***Observação:*** *não seria melhor criar somente o tipo `Root` nessa classe `Db` e não utilizar tudo dentro dela, porque, ai o código da classe pode ser utilizado em outros partes do seu código, a reutilização de código, etc.?*

Comment: Entendi. Sobre colocar em outra classe como você fez o Root, para esse projeto não é necessário pois é somente para estudo mas farei mesmo assim. Obrigado